# Como utilizar HashMap nesse caso?

Tags: java, hashmap

Sou iniciante em Java. Preciso de um programa que leia o nome e número de algumas pessoas e, em seguida, digite um número e o programa retorna o nome da pessoa associada ao número. Me recomendaram usar o HashMap. Se alguém tiver algum exemplo ...

Comment: http://www.devmedia.com.br/hashmap-java-trabalhando-com-listas-key-value/29811

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Testes {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Scanner leitor = new Scanner(System.in);
        HashMap<Integer, String> pessoas = new HashMap<Integer, String>();
        int numero;

        for(int i = 0; i < 5; i++){
            System.out.println("Digite o número da pessoa: ");
            numero = leitor.nextInt();
            System.out.println("Digite o nome da pessoa: ");
            String nome = leitor.next();  // Alteração neste ponto   
            pessoas.put(numero, nome);
        }

        System.out.println("Digite o número da pessoa que você deseja buscar: ");
        numero = leitor.nextInt();

        System.out.println("O nome da pessoa " + numero + " é " + pessoas.get(numero));
    }
}
```

Comment: Perfeito! Só tinha um pequeno erro de digitação na linha String nome = leitor.nextLine(); onde deveria estar next(); 

Obrigado!

Comment: Opa, fico feliz por ter ajudado! :)

Answer (score 1):

O programa abaixo mostra como fazer isso.

Primeiramente, é criada uma lista onde objetos `Pessoa`s são criados e inseridos. Em seguida, percorre-se essa lista a adiciona-se no `HashMap` como chave, o número e como valor o nome da pessoa.

Finalmente, percorre-se a lista novamente e recupera-se do `HashMap`o nome, usando como chave o telefone.

Note que se usou `Map`como interface para se instanciar o `HashMap` pois isso é uma boa prática.

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;

public class HashMapUso {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        // crio lista de pessoas
        List<Pessoa> pessoas = new ArrayList<Pessoa>();
        pessoas.add(new Pessoa("nome1", "numero1"));
        pessoas.add(new Pessoa("nome2", "numero2"));
        pessoas.add(new Pessoa("nome3", "numero3"));

        // mapa onde as pessoas são inseridas
        Map<String, String> pessoaMap = new HashMap<String, String>();

        // dado um número, guardo o nome
        for (Pessoa pessoa : pessoas) {
            pessoaMap.put(pessoa.getNumero(), pessoa.getNome());
        }

        // recupero o nome e o imprimo, dado um número
        for (Pessoa pessoa : pessoas) {
            System.out.println(pessoaMap.get(pessoa.getNumero()));
        }
    }
}

class Pessoa {

    public Pessoa(String nome, String numero) {
        this.nome = nome;
        this.numero = numero;
    }

    private String nome;

    private String numero;

    public String getNome() {
        return nome;
    }

    public void setNome(String nome) {
        this.nome = nome;
    }

    public String getNumero() {
        return numero;
    }

    public void setNumero(String numero) {
        this.numero = numero;
    }


}
```